# How to fix ClassPath in Netbeans on Windows

Tags: java, netbeans, classpath

I just restarted java for university and I have a pretty basic program that I need to code. The thing is every time I try to run it, I get a **NoClassDefFoundError** as follow:

```
run:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: log120/devoir1/LOG120Devoir1
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: log120.devoir1.LOG120Devoir1
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: log120.devoir1.LOG120Devoir1.  Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main" Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I am using Netbeans 7.0.1 since it was the IDE I was using a couple of years ago to code java. I googled the error and found something about the class path but all the example I found were for LINUX based OS so I am kinda lost as to how to set it right on Windows.

The class does exist, the program did compile, from what I understand this error comes when the JVM tries to run the code and does not find the class.

Anyone can help me with finding the ClassPath on Netbeans 7.0.1 or if it is not the ClassPath finding why this error keeps popping up?

Comment: Just FYI, the your text doesn't match the exception, they're actually different exceptions, with different causes/fixes. How are you trying to run the code, from within the IDE, or the command line?

Comment: IDE, i press the play button and I get the error shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to run your own code, setting your classpath is probably barking up the wrong tree.  Netbeans should be including your code automatically on the classpath when it tries to run it.

Please describe how you have your code laid out within your project (eg do you have LOG120Devoir1.java in a log120/devoir1 directory?) as well as how you told netbeans that you wanted to run that class as your main method.

Comment: the .java are under LOG120-Devoir1\src\log120\devoir1. Netbeans made these repertories when i created the java application. When I go in properties => Run => main classes, it says there are no classes to be found. All the classes have the main function (they were made by the IDE) but nothing is running and I am getting the exception